# How to efficiently change the size of sparse vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing, block, sparse-matrix

In Matlab, I have an old 100x1 sparse vector `x`. Now I want to re-allocate its size to a new 200x1 sparse vector `y`, in which the first 100 elements of `y` is the same as `x`. That is, `y` can be regarded as the augmented vector of `x`.

In matlab, my current method is as follows:

`[i, j, s] = find(x);`
`y = sparse(i, j, s, 200, 1);`

But I'm not sure whether there is more efficient way to do it because I just want to resize the old sparse vector `x` from 100x1 to 200x1.

Comment: I'm unsure about efficiency, but regular matrix indexing works just fine, and avoid the explicit use of `find`. `y=sparse(200,1)`, `y(1:100)=x;`.

Comment: But if `y` is sparse, is the index `y(1:100)` efficient?

Comment: I also try `y=[x; sparse(100,1)]`, but it appears to be less efficient.

Comment: What are you planning to do with this vector afterwards? Please elaborate! Just doing `x(200)=0` shouldn't be slow, as any other version of this.

Comment: How about `y=x; y(200)=0`? That should be pretty fast

Comment: The `y=x;y(200)=0` seems to be very much faster than my first suggestion, someone should put it as an answer.